# I cant seem to call my Statefull widget class

Tags: flutter

```
class TagProd extends StatefulWidget {
  const TagProd({super.key});

  @override
  State<TagProd> creatState() {
    return _TagProdState();
  }
}
```

When i run this : i get the following error

Error: The non-abstract class 'TagProd' is missing implementations for these members:

- StatefulWidget.createState
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

Comment: Typo.  "creatState" is not "createState".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overridden method has a typo it should be

```
@override
State<TagProd> createState() {
  return _TagProdState();
}
```

Comment: oh shoot! well, that's embarrassing lol. thank you!!